# how do i query the columns returned

Tags: ruby, activerecord

i created this script in ruby to calculate mfe mae. however it returns a active record and i cannot query its columns.
if i do a `puts["mini"]` i get

```
D:/TradingTools/torontotrader/app/helpers/rb1A5.tmp:28:in '[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from D:/TradingTools/torontotrader/app/helpers/rb1A5.tmp:28
    from D:/TradingTools/torontotrader/app/helpers/rb1A5.tmp:24:in `each'
    from D:/TradingTools/torontotrader/app/helpers/rb1A5.tmp:24
Complete(1)
```

i did a output of details and it is a of type `TickData` and the columsn that i am returning are aggregate type. how can i get the values

```
class TickData < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "tickdata" 
end
class Trades < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "trades" 
end
class TradesReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "tradesreport" 
end

sql="select * from tradesreport where entry>=(select  min(time)  from tickdata ) and exitt <=(select  max(time)  from tickdata )"

tradestocalculate= Trades.find_by_sql(sql) 
tradestocalculate.each {|item|
  sql="select MIN(LASTPRICE) as mini,MAX(LASTPRICE) as  maxi,COUNT(*) as no from tickdata where time >='#{item['entry']}' AND time <= '#{item['exitt']}' and 
symbol like '%#{item['symbol_alias'][0,3]}%'"
  details= TickData.find_by_sql(sql)
  puts  details["mini"]
```

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong. Active Record is an orm not an sql library. For that you'd use sequel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is in `details[0]['mini']`, `details[0]['maxi']` and `details[0]['no']`